# Ошибка при работе со списком

Tags: python, list, indexerror

Пишу цикл для удаления людей из списка, мне выдаёт ошибку

> IndexError: pop index out of range.

Список состоит из 6 человек, но ошибку выдаёт при попытке удалить более 3-х. В чём дело?

```
guests = ['Яся', 'Оля', 'Вадим']
for guest in guests:
    print(f'Привет, {guest}!')
print('Оля прийти не сможет')
guests[1] = 'Лера'
for guest in guests:
    print(f'Ну вы-то, {guest}, приходите')
new_guests = ['Катя', 'Орлов', 'Никита']
guests.insert(0, new_guests[0])
guests.insert(2, new_guests[1])
guests.append(new_guests[2])
for guest in guests:
    print(f'{guest}, добро пожаловать!')
for i in range(0, 3):
    popped_friends = guests.pop(i)
    print(popped_friends, 'bye')
    print(guests)
```

Comment: Если у тебя 6 и ты удалил 3, то сколько осталось? Что будет в этом случае удалять pop(4), например?

Comment: Да, логично, понял. А как в таком случае можно сделать так, чтобы он удалил именно 4-х гостей? Только вручную?

Comment: А какая логика удаления, каких именно гостей надо удалять? Если из начала, то pop[0] несколько раз